# Set value of object using a string as the key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string representing the keys in an object.  Here's an example:

```
var obj = {
    test: 12,
    high: {
      sky: {
        val: 14
      }
    },
    low: [1, 2, 3]
},
keys = 'high.sky.val';
```

So, I want to set the value of `obj.high.sky.val` (with `'high.sky.val'` being in a string).

I know how to read the value (though, this may not be the best way):

```
var keyPieces = keys.split('.'), value = obj;
keyPieces.forEach(function(x){
   value = value[x];
});
console.log(value); // 14
```

I can't figure out how to set `obj.high.sky.val` (without using `eval`).

How can I set the value of a property in an object, if that key is a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
function setKey(key, value, targetObject) {
  var keys = key.split('.'), obj = targetObject || window, keyPart;
  while ((keyPart = keys.shift()) && keys.length) {
    obj = obj[keyPart];
  }
  obj[keyPart] = value;
}
```

Edit: The previous version wouldn't have worked with "no-dot" keys... Fixed.

Comment: How do I tell it what object to use?

Comment: Hang on, editing. I assumed you wanted to start resolving from the global object... there you go, now it can optionally have a target object (otherwise it defaults to `window`). If you don't want the `window` default, just remove " || window".

Answer (score 5):

I actually had to make a couple of functions to achieve this end when working in GameMaker:HTML5

```
function js_get(varname) {
    if( varname.indexOf(".") < 0)
        return window[varname];
    else {
        var curr = window, steps = varname.split("."), next;
        while(next = steps.shift()) curr = curr[next];
        return curr;
    }
}
function js_set(varname,value) {
    if( varname.indexOf(".") < 0)
        window[varname] = value;
    else {
        var curr = window, steps = varname.split("."), next, last = steps.pop();
        while(next = steps.shift()) curr = curr[next];
        curr[last] = value;
    }
}
```

This works because objects are passed by reference in JS.

Comment: In my code, I tried doing `value = 1000;`, and it didn't update the value.  I guess I needed to stop at the 2nd to last object, and then set the value.  Why didn't `value = 1000;` work?

Comment: That's what this code does, with the `last = steps.pop()`. I just double-checked it, and it does work. Another test: `a = {b:{c:1}}; d = a.b; d.c = 2; alert(a.b.c); // alerts 2, not 1`

Comment: Weird.  `a = {b:{c:1}}; d = a.b.c; d = 2; alert(a.b.c);` alerts 1.  Wonder why that is.  I guess because `d` was set to a value (int), not an object.  That would make sense.

Comment: You missed a bit - I assigned `d = a.b`, and `d.c = 2`. That's why this works.

Answer (score 2):

```
function setDeep(el, key, value) {
    key = key.split('.');
    var i = 0, n = key.length;
    for (; i < n-1; ++i) {
        el = el[key[i]];
    }
    return el[key[i]] = value;
}

function getDeep(el, key) {
    key = key.split('.');
    var i = 0, n = key.length;
    for (; i < n; ++i) {
        el = el[key[i]];
    }
    return el;
}
```

and you can use it thus:

```
setDeep(obj, 'high.sky.val', newValue);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `el[key[i]]`?

Comment: According to @Kolink's answer, you need to stop at the 2nd to last property when setting, so that `el` is an object, and not an int.  Also, when getting, you needed to use `el[key[i]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pair of functions to set and get values. I just threw together an example.

`objGet` takes an object and key string. It will attempt to get the value. If it can't find it it will return undefined.

`objSet` takes an object, key string and value. It will attempt to find and set the value. If it can't (because of a bad key string) it will return undefined. Else it returns the value passed.

```
function objGet(obj, keyString) {
    for(var keys = keyString.split('.'), i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        obj = obj[keys[i]];
        if(obj === undefined) return undefined;
    }
    return obj;
}

function objSet(obj, keyString, val) {
    for(var keys = keyString.split('.'), i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l - 1; i++) {
        obj = obj[keys[i]];
        if(obj === undefined) return undefined;
    }
    if(obj[keys[l - 1]] === undefined) return undefined;
    obj[keys[l - 1]] = val;
    return val;
}


//// TESTING

var obj = {
    test: 12,
    high: {
        sky: {
            val: 14
        }
    },
    low: [1, 2, 3]
};

objGet(obj, 'test'); // returns 12
objGet(obj, 'high.sky.val'); // returns 14
objGet(obj, 'high.sky.non.existant'); // returns undefined

objSet(obj, 'test', 999); // return 999
obj.test; // 999

objSet(obj, 'high.sky.non.existant', 1234); // returns undefined
obj.high.sky; // { val: 14 }

objSet(obj, 'high.sky.val', 111); // returns 111
obj.high.sky; // { val: 111 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an important question and I needed a variant, that allows for arrays nested in the objects AND for deep creation of non-existant fields.
I know you specified 'object' but in reality an object can also hold arrays.
In this situation the otherwise excellent code by @Marshall didn't help me out.
So I started fiddling and got the following code (hope this helps anyone):

```
function objGet(obj, keyString) {
    // allow for arrays, returns undefined for non-existant-fields.
    var keys=[{label:"",type:"field",is_array:false}], current_key=0;
    for(var i=0;i<keyString.length;i++)
{
        var c=keyString.charAt(i);
        switch(c)
        {
            case ".":
                current_key++;
                keys[current_key]={label:"",type:"field",is_array:false};
            break;
            case "[":
                keys[current_key].is_array=true;
                current_key++;
                keys[current_key]={label:"",type:"index",is_array:false};
            break;
            case "]": 
            break;
            default:
                keys[current_key].label+=c;
        }
    }
    var part=obj;
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) 
    {
        var label=keys[i].label;
        if(i==keys.length-1)
        {
            return part[label];
            }else{
            if(part[label] === undefined)
            {
                    return undefined;
                }
                part = part[label];
            }
        }
    }

function objSet(obj, keyString, val) {
// allows for arrays, deep creates non-existant fields.
    var keys=[{label:"",type:"field",is_array:false}], current_key=0;
    for(var i=0;i<keyString.length;i++)
    {
        var c=keyString.charAt(i);
        switch(c)
        {
            case ".":
                current_key++;
                keys[current_key]={label:"",type:"field",is_array:false};
            break;
            case "[":
                keys[current_key].is_array=true;
                current_key++;
                keys[current_key]={label:"",type:"index",is_array:false};
            break;
        case "]": 
        break;
            default:
            keys[current_key].label+=c;
        }
    }
    var part=obj;
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) 
    {
        var label=keys[i].label;
        if(i==keys.length-1)
        {
            part[label] = val;
    }else{
        if(part[label] === undefined)
        {
            // we need to create it for deep set!
            if(keys[i].is_array)
            {
                part[label]=[];
            }else{
                part[label]={};
            }
        }
            part = part[label];
        }
    }
}

// TESTS
var obj = {
    test: 12,
    high: {
        sky: {
            val: 14
        }
    },
    kneedeep: [
                {something:"som0",something_else:"elze0"},
                {something:"som1",something_else:"elze1"}
              ],
    low: [1, 2, 3]
};
var obj_str=JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("testing with object: "+obj_str);
 // TEST GET
console.log("test: "+objGet(obj, 'test')); // returns 999
console.log("high.sky.non.existant: "+objGet(obj, 'high.sky.non.existant')); // returns undefined
console.log("kneedeep[0].something: "+objGet(obj, 'kneedeep[0].something')); // returns "som0"
console.log("kneedeep[1].something_else: "+objGet(obj, 'kneedeep[1].something_else')); // returns "elze1"
console.log("high.sky.val: "+objGet(obj, 'high.sky.val')); // returns 14
console.log("low[0]: "+objGet(obj, 'low[0]')); // returns  1


  // TEST SET

objSet(obj, 'test', 999); // return 999
console.log("result SET 'test', 999:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj=JSON.parse(obj_str); // reset the object
objSet(obj, 'high.sky.non.existant', 1234); // creates the necessary objects.
console.log("result SET 'high.sky.non.existant', 1234:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj=JSON.parse(obj_str); // reset the object
objSet(obj, 'high.sky.val', 111); 
console.log("result SET 'high.sky.val', 111:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj=JSON.parse(obj_str); // reset the object
objSet(obj, 'kneedeep[0].something', 111); 
console.log("result SET 'kneedeep[0].something', 111:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj=JSON.parse(obj_str); // reset the object
objSet(obj, 'kneedeep[1].something_else', 1234); 
console.log("result SET 'kneedeep[1].something_else', 1234:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Needed an implementation that worked with arrays, this worked wonderfully. You're a lifesaver. :D