# Is there any way to set a style for a DOM object with a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have here some code, in which I am trying to change all of something on a page.

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

var tag = '.style.backgroundColor';
var val = 'black';

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length;i++) {
  allElements[i] + tag = val;
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336148/set-value-of-object-using-a-string-as-the-key Using the answer `setKey('style.backgroundColor', 'black', allElements[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but not the way you are doing it. You'll need to pass (as an index, using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)) the CSS property name (a string) into the object returned by accessing the `.style` property.

Also, [don't use `.getElementsByTagName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) as it's a 25+ year old API that returns a "live" node list, which can hurt performance. Instead, use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over the returned collection with the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, which is an alternative to a traditional `for` counting loop that is a bit easier to work with since you don't have to manage any loop counters and get direct access to the element you are iterating.

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

var tag = 'backgroundColor'; // Just store the name of the CSS property
var val = 'black';

// Use the more modern Array.forEach() method of looping
allElements.forEach(function(element){
  element.style[tag] = val; // Pass the style object's property name as an index
});
```

```css
* { color:white; border:2px solid white; }
```

```html
<div>This is a div<br>that spans two lines.<div>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
<h1>And a Heading 1</h1>
```